# Slack closes down on suspend

Tags: thinkpad, 21.04, slack

Running Ubuntu 21.04 on ThinkPad X1 Carbon 9th generation. When I suspend the computer, Slack closes down. Happens every time. Notified Slack, but wondering if anyone else here has encountered this.

UPDATE: See below. Going back to 20.04.3 fixed the issue, and Slack is working on it.

Comment: Everything was fine previously, but today Slack closes every time my screen times out. I'll make a coffee, come back and unlock the screen, and Slack is gone. No trouble reopening it. Slack snap version:
slack 4.19.2 44 latest/stable slack✓ classic I don't think the hardware is the problem, based on others having the same issue, but... my machine is:
Lenovo P14s Gen 2i (11th gen i7, 16GB), Ubuntu 21.04, Gnome 3.38.5, X11, hybrid graphics mode with nvidia driver 470. I've notified Slack, too, and linked this page.

Comment: Same issue for me, ThinkPad E480 and Ubuntu 20.10. The problem started when it updated to the latest version 4.19.2. Apart from the issues commented here, if I try to upload some file to a Slack channel or open an APP it closes suddenly

Comment: I'm on 20.04.3, never upgraded to 21.04. Have the same issue

Comment: If anyone's interested, Brendan Gregg investigated and found the source of the issue: https://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2021-08-27/slack-crashes-secret-stderr.html

Answer (score 14):

Try removing Slack cache directory *after verifying slack is closed*:

```
rm -r ~/snap/slack/common/.cache
```

So steps are:

1. Close slack
2. Delete cache folder via rm -rf ~/snap/slack/common/.cache
3. Re-run slack, lock computer and verify it's still there
4. think about it.. And miss the quite period when slack was shut down and you didn't notice, or - "didn't notice"

Answer (score 5):

I went back to 20.04.3, which solved the problem.

Slack is aware of the issue and is working on it.

Comment: Or just delete `~/snap/slack/common/.cache`, that fixed it for me. Found here: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/slack-crashes-when-lock-screen-or-screen-saver-is-activated/26189/11

Comment: Strangely, the bug never occurs when Slack is launched directly by CLI, but only when launched by systemd (this happens when you click on the desktop shortcut)